# PHP compile without memory limit

Tags: php

I want to compile `PHP7` without memory and timeout limit module.
Is it possible, or does anyone have experience?

As stated in the PHP documentation:

> Compile with memory limit support. (not available since PHP 5.2.1 - always enabled)

Is there any possibility to compile without the module?

Comment: You cannot remove the memory limit at compile time, but you CAN set the `memory_limit` to -1 in php.ini or via `ini_set`, which has the same effect.

Comment: And you should avoid hosting PHP without time/memory limits on your web server.

Comment: thx, i dont want to use it as an hosted php version, i want to use them as an "service", regards

Comment: Uhhmmm may I ask what it is you are doing and why you (think you) need to compile without mem limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can effectively disable memory limits in PHP at compile time by replacing

```
static PHP_INI_MH(OnChangeMemoryLimit)
{
    if (new_value) {
        PG(memory_limit) = zend_atol(ZSTR_VAL(new_value), (int)ZSTR_LEN(new_value));
    } else {
        PG(memory_limit) = 1<<30;       /* effectively, no limit */
    }
    return zend_set_memory_limit(PG(memory_limit));
}
```

with

```
static PHP_INI_MH(OnChangeMemoryLimit)
{
    PG(memory_limit) = 1<<30;       /* effectively, no limit */
    return zend_set_memory_limit(PG(memory_limit));
}
```

in /main/main.c

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9bcd2bcc21b7739a03acbe4e86dea1efef98c7fd/main/main.c#L157

keeping in mind that that this function is called once during initialization to set "default value", that should be sufficient :)

similarly, i think all that's needed to effectively disable max_execution_time is a small patch to the `static PHP_INI_MH(OnUpdateTimeout)` function, just replace `if (stage==PHP_INI_STAGE_STARTUP)`  with `if(1)` at the beginning of the function ( https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9bcd2bcc21b7739a03acbe4e86dea1efef98c7fd/main/main.c#L299 ) , and it should effectively stay unlimited forever. haven't actually tested it tho